# GPS Provider of Location Manager returns (very) incorrect coordinates

Tags: android, gps

I am retrieving the user location:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false); // GPS

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

The provider string is GPS. `getLastKnownLocation` returns the coordinates of where I live, not where I currently am. The distance is 35 miles away. The phone GPS was on as I drive into work. Yet when I run my app on my phone using Android Studio, it returns the latitude and longitude of where I live, not where I am. Why is this happening?

Comment: you should try Fused location provider for getting accurate locations. here is the url for fused location provider : https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Answer (score 1):

In order to get accurate current location, you need to use Fused location provider, A great example using Fused location provider. you can find [here](https://github.com/sakurabird/Android-Fused-location-provider-example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sakurafish/exam/location/api/MainActivity.java)!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
locationManager = 
      (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
Location location = getLastKnownLocation();

private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
    Location bestLocation = null;
    for (String provider : providers) {
        Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


        if (l == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (bestLocation == null
                || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
            bestLocation = l;

        }
    }
    if (bestLocation == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return bestLocation;
 }
```